# Obter último filho de uma categoria de produtos

Tags: php, wordpress, loop, woocommerce

Galera, boa tarde.

Estou precisando obter o ultimo filho de uma categoria dentro um loop de produtos:

```
Categoria
-categoria filho
--categoria ultimo filho
```

Isso me dar sempre o Pai, ou seja, 'Categoria':

```
   <?php

        $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
        $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats );

        if( ! empty( $product_cats ) ) {

            $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats );
            $top_term = $single_cat;

            if( $top_term->parent > 0 ) {
                while( $top_term->parent > 0 ) {
                    $top_term = get_term( $top_term->parent, 'product_cat' );
                }
            } else {
               $attr = 'sem parent';
            }

            $attr = $top_term->slug;
        } else {
            $attr = 'sem categoria';
        }
?>
```

Comment: André Ribeiro, ajuda awe, man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_get_object_terms()` é seu amigo aqui. Uma vez que você tem o ID do post, chame `wp_get_object_terms($post_ID)`, e ele irá retornar um array contendo todas as categorias associadas à ele, e fazendo a referencia de quem é pai de quem. Assim, você consegue descobrir qual é a última delas.

*Bonus*: Este método recebe mais de um parâmetro, portanto você pode usá-lo com taxonomias customizadas também, além de filtrar o retorno desejado. Leia sobre ele no [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms).